# Postgres Trigger function - Pg 9.1

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, postgresql-9.1

There is a table on my database that stores a path for video files used by my website. Those files are stored in a SSD disk.

```
path character varying(255)
id serial
```

The path will always be like this:

```
/files/client/\d+/(attachment|user)/\d+/(main|thumbnail)
```

Here are some examples of valid paths:

```
/files/client/743052/attachment/2123598/main
/files/client/743052/attachment/2123598/thumbnail
/files/client/1475296/user/3541234/main
/files/client/1475296/user/3541234/thumbnail
```

**Question:**
How can I create a Trigger that checks the value `WHEN INSERTED` and, if the row is less than the minimal path (`/files/client/\d+/(attachment|user)/\d+/(main|thumbnail)`) then raise an exception?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

**UPDATE:**

Some more examples here:

```
/files/client/45345/user/3542341234/main -- PASS
/files/client/45345/user/3542341234/thumbnail -- PASS
/files/client/253623/attachment/35334/main -- PASS
/files/client/253623/attachment/35334/thumbnail -- PASS
/files/client/45312341245/users/12545/main -- WRONG!
/files/client/45312341245/users/12545/thumbnail -- WRONG!
/files/client/45345/attachment/1223545/mains -- WRONG!
/files/client/45345/attachment/1223545/thumbnails -- WRONG!
```

Comment: What does that even mean, "if the row is less than the minimal path" how can that occur?

Comment: If for some reason the application inserts wrong path, I want the DB to be able to "block" it. Simple like that

Comment: What is "the wrong path" how do you have a "less than the minimal path" can you give us an example?

Comment: @EvanCarroll I've already given it to u: Path should be always `/files/client/\d+/(attachment|user)/\d+/(main|thumbnail)`. Anything different from that is wrong.

Comment: ahh, I had no idea that's what you mean when you say minimal. You just mean matches that regex.

Comment: @EvanCarroll no problem.. please see my latest update

Comment: I updated my answr to show an example of normalizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a check constraint however I would personally restructure my schema. Essentially what you seem to be doing is serializing a lot of data into a path, and then you want to be sure it's correct. That's kind of yuck, from my perspective.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id    serial,
  path  text
    CHECK ( path ~ '/files/client/\d+/(attachment|user)/\d+/(main|thumbnail)' )
);
INSERT INTO foo(path) VALUES 
  ('/files/client/743052/attachment/2123598/main'),
  ('/files/client/743052/attachment/2123598/thumbnail'),
  ('/files/client/1475296/user/3541234/main'),
  ('/files/client/1475296/user/3541234/thumbnail');

INSERT INTO foo(path) VALUES ('/STUD/EVAN/beefcake_hotstuff.jpg');
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "foo_path_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, /STUD/EVAN/beefcake_hotstuff.jpg).
```

I would probably go the opposite direction and normalize to some degree.

## Normalizing

Normalizing would look something like this,

```
CREATE SCHEMA aws;

CREATE TABLE aws.client (
  client_id serial PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE aws.attachment (
  client_id       int REFERENCES client,
  attachment_id   int PRIMARY KEY,
  name            text
);
CREATE TABLE aws.user (
  client_id       int REFERENCES client,
  user_id         int PRIMARY KEY,
  name            text
);

SELECT '/files/client' || client_id || '/attachment' || attachment_id || '/' || a.name
FROM aws.attachment AS a
JOIN aws.client AS c USING (client_id);
```